# Change a default value for xparse command optional argument

Tags: macros, xparse

Suppose I create a command with `xparse`

```
NewDocumentCommand{\myCommand}{ m O{} }{ #1 and #2 }
```

Could I later in my document change the default value of arg two? Maybe something along these lines?

```
\def\@myCommand@args@II{New Default}
```

(II denotes the second argument)

So that later on, `\myCommand{Hello}` produces "Hello and New Default"

Comment: Probably specifying the default with a macro that you can later change the definition of.

Comment: @egreg good point--I should be able to use O{\ArgDefault} in the argument spec.

Comment: Will `\myCommand` be component of a moving argument? Will `\myCommand` be, e.g., component of a sectioning-command which ends up in the table of contents and in the bookmarks and in page-headers as well? "moving arguments" in LaTeX are macro-arguments which are carried out at several points of time during compilation so that at one point in time the definition of a macro-token which is component of such a "moving argument" might differ from the definition which the macro-token in question has at another point in time although at each point in time you wish to obtain the same textual phrase...

Answer (score 2):

You might do

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\myCommand}{ m O{\DefaultArgForMyCommand} }{ #1 and #2 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefaultArgForMyCommand}{}{}% initially empty
```

and then do

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\DefaultArgForMyCommand}{}{whatever}
```

when you want that the optional argument changes its default value.

However, I can't recommend doing this unless you know without any possible doubt what's the value of `\DefaultArgForMyCommand` at any given point (I'm not sure you can).